# How to use MATCH in ON statement on a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, match

I'm trying to use a MATCH statement on a LEFT JOIN but I keep getting:

```
 Incorrect arguments to AGAINST
```

This is what I am trying:

```
SELECT *
FROM Posts
LEFT JOIN `Follow_Searches` 
ON MATCH(`Posts`.`B`) AGAINST (`Follow_Searches`.`B`)
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That cannot be done. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match):

> Full-text searching is performed using MATCH() ... AGAINST syntax. MATCH() takes a comma-separated list that names the columns to be searched. AGAINST takes a string to search for, and an optional modifier that indicates what type of search to perform. **The search string must be a literal string, not a variable or a column name.**

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

JOINing data, you must specify the fields on which your data will be joind after the keyword ON (e.g. ON table1.id = table2.id).

Maybe in your case you should do a Cartesian multiply and use MATCH-AGAINST or other comparison function in WHERE.